# TypeScript: Insert Json Object into Cookie

Tags: json, angular, typescript, cookies

I have an issue with JSON object, I need to insert a JSON object in Cookie but the JSON object corrupted when inserted in the cookie

---

**Expected:**

```
{
  "access_token": "s0HvwP7PIUwgMI8_oVPpju9W9NK3f2973SLtZnmbJYi23qgwftYY-P9MtqBcfK43_bh3e_dZwXC5xyU29CkJJmO5C5Du7TMf5LULJWXjo7AdEHTG0tlWwFMudQ9GjX58Ba80x-oVC7_Zn25Ay18CQ_7egQO9yWmjwXI1fha1x7NF6xUA-zKkCNE8ypyJ5aJENdKhA04xWd6d7DwjXcEgGRC5LgGhh9IhoQ2_2APfoPS7XE5T-04NQmVjfVuxKWLT",
  "token_type": "bearer",
  "expires_in": 86399
}
```

**Inserted:**

> %7B%22access_token%22%3A%22s0HvwP7PIUwgMI8_oVPpju9W9NK3f2973SLtZnmbJYi23qgwftYY-P9MtqBcfK43_bh3e_dZwXC5xyU29CkJJmO5C5Du7TMf5LULJWXjo7AdEHTG0tlWwFMudQ9GjX58Ba80x-oVC7_Zn25Ay18CQ_7egQO9yWmjwXI1fha1x7NF6xUA-zKkCNE8ypyJ5aJENdKhA04xWd6d7DwjXcEgGRC5LgGhh9IhoQ2_2APfoPS7XE5T-04NQmVjfVuxKWLT%22%2C%22token_type%22%3A%22bearer%22%2C%22expires_in%22%3A86399%7D

---

**This is my code in Typescript:**

```
this.cookie.addCookie('currentUser', JSON.stringify(user));
```

Comment: What's `this.cookie`? How have you determined what was inserted?

Comment: it is https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-cookies that i used for cookies stuff

Comment: And? How are you determining that the wrong value was set?

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp `%22` is code for quotation marks and `%3A` is for `:`. you are probably url encoding somewhere

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From reading [the code](https://github.com/BCJTI/ng2-cookies/blob/32e48d43f67cf86eabe192418c935ce11bab8714/src/cookie.ts), it looks like `ng2-cookies` always URL encodes values when adding them to a cookie and URL decodes them when retrieving the value.

As long as you always use that library, this should be fine. (Values should round-trip without problems.) But if you are trying to read the cookie outside of this library, you're going to end up seeing the URL-encoded value, and you'll have to manually decode (e.g. via `decodeURIComponent` in JavaScript).